# Import FBX to Blender loses all material slots

Tags: materials, unreal-engine

I have a skeletal mesh exported from UE4 with 12 material slots, but when I import it to Blender all of the material slots are missing. I assigned materials to the slots in UE4 before exporting. I'm using UE 4.26 and Blender 2.93.1. Any ideas how to get the material slots to show up in Blender?

Thanks

Comment: An update to the above, noticed that when I uncheck 'export morph targets' when exporting from UE4, the materials slots show up in Blender!  However we also need to keep the morph targets in tact. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else comes across this issue, here's a solution/workaround:

https://developer.blender.org/T84111